# Lodash isEqual comparison with specific property lowercase

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a `lodash` approach for comparing two objects where a certain property is compared in a case-insensitive manner

```js
const obj1 = { name: 'Dave', course: 'Math' };
const obj2 = { name: 'dave', course: 'Math' };
```

The comparison would be case-insensitive for `name`, but strict equality for other properties

Was thinking something along the lines of the following (obviously for example only):

```js
var result = _.isEqual(
  _.omit(obj1, ['creation', 'deletion']),
  _.omit(obj2, ['creation', 'deletion'])
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `_.isEqualWith()` to compare the objects with a customizer. If the key (3rd customizer param) is `name` make an insensitive comparison, for other keys return `undefined` to use the default comparison.

```js
const obj1 = { name: 'Dave', course: 'Math' };
const obj2 = { name: 'dave', course: 'Math' };

const insensetiveStrCompare = (v1, v2) =>
  !v1.localeCompare(v2, undefined, { sensitivity: 'accent' }) // returns 0 if equal, and !0 === true

const result = _.isEqualWith(
  obj1, 
  obj2, 
  (v1, v2, key) => key === 'name' ? 
    insensetiveStrCompare(v1, v2)
    :
    undefined
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```